# Matrix by category in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I want to display my totals by category in Matix and limited 5 columns( +1 header). 
How can I achieve it?
I mean I want to get each total for respective ItemID, and I want to display in matrix by running order of ItemID. I want to achieve my matrix as follow: [Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opjPz.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj9EV.jpg)

Comment: Can you show sample data and how the grid looks now?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/202t06/9 @WEI_DBA can you view the picture? I've tried adding in the question too. But not sure, can be able to view???

Comment: And I dun have access to edit the data- I mean I couldn't make calculation and pull it out as a new data set.

Comment: Question still isn't clear even after the image. Are you saying you want to restrict the number of columns to 5 categories/Columns? If so, that you would need to do via the query, getting the first 4 and grouping the rest as say 'Others'.

Comment: @VKarthik .exactly. For limiting number of columns in matrix, we could probably achieve putting inside a rectangle. It will go to next line if exceeded. I guess. I have seen people using custom code or editing inside the query. As for my case, I have no access to amend the original query and using custom code either.

Comment: Ok, I understand your question now. Let me work on it and will get back. You may be able to achieve this by adding a new row, not fully sure now. I will work on a POC

Comment: sure Thanks @VKarthik

Comment: @VKarthik, any news?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. Got occupied with some work and I was working on it on the side but wasn't able to get it working. This is one link I came close to your requirement but that again would require some changes to the code - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c72824f-1562-47b2-a107-1148dbda2a2f/ssrs-matrix-column-break?forum=sqlreportingservices. Hope that helps.